# Can't Bundle Install with charlock_holmes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I just clone a existing rails app. And when I did `bundle install` I got this error.

```
Installing charlock_holmes 0.7.7 with native extensions
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /var/folders/2w/y33q15_n15998ckfl1pxr8qc0000gn/T/bundler20240226-22183-f2wt9scharlock_holmes-0.7.7/gems/charlock_holmes-0.7.7 for
inspection.
Results logged to
/var/folders/2w/y33q15_n15998ckfl1pxr8qc0000gn/T/bundler20240226-22183-f2wt9scharlock_holmes-0.7.7/extensions/universal-darwin-23/2.6.0/charlock_holmes-0.7.7/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing charlock_holmes (0.7.7), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install charlock_holmes -v '0.7.7' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'` succeeds before bundling.

In Gemfile:
  rails_admin_import was resolved to 2.3.1, which depends on
    charlock_holmes
```

And then I run `gem install charlock_holmes -v '0.7.7' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'`

```
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing charlock_holmes:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/charlock_holmes-0.7.7/ext/charlock_holmes
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/bin/ruby -I /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0 -r ./siteconf20240226-22441-1mmmm1m.rb extconf.rb
checking for -licui18n... yes
checking for unicode/ucnv.h... yes
checking for -lz... yes
checking for -licuuc... yes
checking for -licudata... yes
creating Makefile

current directory: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/charlock_holmes-0.7.7/ext/charlock_holmes
make "DESTDIR=" clean

current directory: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/charlock_holmes-0.7.7/ext/charlock_holmes
make "DESTDIR="
compiling converter.c
compiling encoding_detector.c
encoding_detector.c:31:32: warning: '(' and '{' tokens introducing statement expression appear in different macro expansion contexts [-Wcompound-token-split-by-macro]
        rb_hash_aset(rb_match, ID2SYM(rb_intern("type")), ID2SYM(rb_intern("text")));
                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
...

Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/charlock_holmes-0.7.7 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/extensions/universal-darwin-23/2.6.0/charlock_holmes-0.7.7/gem_make.out
```

I already run `brew install icu4c`  and `brew install openssl` too.

What's happened here? Am I need to use ruby 2.3.3? Since I can only use Ruby 2.6.0 above.

Full Logs: https://gist.github.com/alphadc/246af58ad2185fe0093a0e8eaa9bcda6

Comment: just tried with 2.7.8 and no problem. perhaps it is a compiler issue (brew update; brew upgrade); if ... summarized the results, perhaps try not to, I'd expect the errors to be in that output and/or the logs, perhaps add it completely.

Comment: Hi @murb , the full log is here - https://gist.github.com/alphadc/246af58ad2185fe0093a0e8eaa9bcda6

Comment: sorry, I was hoping to see something else than 'warning'... I suspect there is some homebrew / compilor thing, but typically brute forcing these things by updating homebrew; removing all gems from system and reinstalling everything. sorry